# Angular Material Stepper and Step separately components

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to separate my steps from stepper, because I don't know how many steps I have in each page (it can change).

Page:

```
<test-stepper>
  <test-step></test-step>
  <test-step></test-step>
</test-stepper>
```

Stepper:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper>
  <ng-content select="test-step"></ng-content>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

Step:

```
<mat-step>
  <ng-template matStepLabel>Label</ng-template>

  <div>
    <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
  </div>

</mat-step>
```

I did this, but it not show any step. I added the mat-stepper provider in test-step. I saw cdk-step, but I want to use material stepper style.

Thanks all :D

Comment: Hi! Any solution?